# Internal Server error in register html page

Tags: python, html, sql, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a register page for a website. I don't think the form is the problem since I've implemented that before.

I'm having trouble with getting the users input, hashing the password, and inserting it and all the other data into a table using SQL. I also have conditions (username isn't unique, or if nothing is typed into the fields).

when I run flask run, I would get a 500 error.

here is what I wrote:

register.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Register
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    
    <form action="/register" method="post">
     
     <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"><br>
        
     <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br>
     
     <input type="text" name="password" id="pass" placeholder="password"><br>
     
     <input type="text" name="confirm" id="confirm" placeholde="confirm"><br>
     
     <pre> </pre>
     
     <input type="submit" value= "Submit Form">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

application.py:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""
    

    if request.method == "POST":

        #if input isn't typed
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return render_template("failuser.html")
    
        if not request.form.get("password"):
            return render_template("failpass.html")
            
        if not request.form.get("confirm"):
            return render_template("failpass.html")  
            
        if request.form.get("password") != request.form.get("confirm"):
            return render_template("failpass.html")  
        
        #if username already exists
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username =: username" ,request.form.get("username"))
        
        if len(rows) >= 1:
            return render_template("failuser.html")
        
        #insert info into table    
        db.execute("INSERT INTO users(username, hash, email) VALUES (:username, :password, :email)",
                   username = request.form.get("username"),
                   hash=generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password")),
                   email=request.form.get("email"))
        
        #remember user           
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM rows WHERE username = :username",
                   username=request.form.get("username"))   
                   
        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]
        
        return render_template("/index")
    
    else:
        return render_template("/register")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the last four lines :

```
        return render_template("/index")
    
    else:
        return render_template("/register")
```

You are trying to return html pages instead you (probably) want to redirect them to that url.

Instead of render_template use redirect